# Android - Get recent searches from Places API

Tags: android, google-places-api, autocompletetextview

I would like to emulate the "Recent Search" functionality of Google Maps.

Specifically I have an AutoCompleteTextView hooked up with the Google Places API. If the user focuses the AutoCompleteTextView (threshold 0), I would like to return the two most recent searches and have an option to search all recent searches.

I looked at the documentation and could not find a public method for returning recent history. Is this something I will have to store on my own web service and retrieve manually? Or does Google offer something like this to the public?

**Example** 
[image]